# Rounding numbers

Tags: matlab, rounding

I'm trying to make Matlab round numbers to numbers on certain interval. I have a large vector and I need to round them up to or down.

```
% Input
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

% Interval of allowed numbers.
dE = 3;

% Rounding
B = round(A,dE); % Does not work like I desire.

% Desired output
B == [0 3 3 3 6 6 6 9 9 9 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% Input
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

% Interval of allowed numbers.
dE = 3;

% Rounding
B = round(A/dE)*dE;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't round integers, so you need to divide it by the desired interval, `dE`. After rounding, you can multiply it by `dE` again.

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
% Interval of allowed numbers.
dE = 3;    
B = dE * round(A / dE)
B =
     0     3     3     3     6     6     6     9     9     9
```